# How can I connect to MongoDb Mvc 4?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been running a solution with multiple projects that can connect to / update etc MongoDb. These projects are c# dll and c# excel projects (and unit test projects).

I now have another solution with an asp.net mvc 4 project and am using the same code to try and read from the same MongoDb. An example call code is:

```
const string RESULT = "000000000000000000000000";
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoServerSettings"].ConnectionString;
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("test");
var entityCollection = db.GetCollection<MyObj>("Test");

var test = entityCollection.AsQueryable().Single(x => x.Id == RESULT);
```

The error I get in the new asp.net project is:

```
Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: Request for the permission of type    'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

The connection string is the same as the successful solution but is now added to the web.config file:

```
 <add name="MongoServerSettings" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/test" />
```

I haven't used any reference to System.Net.SocketPermission in the first solution (I don't think).

**Can you spot if this is some trivial mistake that I'm making? Please let me know if I've missed off important info and I will update.**

Please note I am very new to this exciting world of software development so please excuse any lax terminology. Also, I have Sql server running on another web server which could do the job but I'm keen to use MongoDb as everything is in place to use it already.

**EDIT**
As WiredPrairie mentions below, all I needed to do was simply change the trust level from Medium to Full.

Comment: Seems like your app may be running in a less than full trust mode, which means that some capabilities are limited.

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie, this solves it!

Comment: Or, you can create a custom trust profile as well that includes just the permissions needed by your application. (It's well known/ documented procedure)

Comment: Yes a custom trust does seem a bit more sensible. Thanks